# How to insert a series of numbers into a matrix?

Tags: python

As an example, I have a 9x9 matrix:

```py
x=[
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
]
```

and I want to insert a series of numbers like the example:

```py
aux=900000001051200030000980000680740000730000908010058670008100000002007090190004060
```

I want to be able to put each digit into an individual position of the matrix, but I am a little stuck on attacking this problem.

Comment: `in an individual position`, can you specify what you mean?

Comment: Is `aux` always going to be a 81-digit integer, or is it possible that it might be shorter? In which case, can we suppose the highest digits are `0`?

Answer (score 1):

- This oneliner works by splitting by 9 and mapping to integers again.
- `for i in range(0, len(str(aux)), 9)` This will iterate over chunks of size 9.
- `list(map(int, aux[i,i+9]))` This will map each character from string to int and create list of it. You can see `map` function in python for more info.
- Above two steps combined in list comprehension will give you list of lists.

```py
aux=900000001051200030000980000680740000730000908010058670008100000002007090190004060 # assumption 81 digit number or string ?
m = [list(map(int, str(aux)[i:i+9])) for i in range(0, len(str(aux)), 9)]
print(m)
```

- Output

```
[[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [6, 8, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 8, 6, 7, 0],
 [0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0],
 [1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0]]
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit about the functions ?

Comment: @DaniloSantos Added some explanation. You can read about map and list comprehension to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

The following code by using Python 3.7 will do the job for you:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # size of the array n x n
    n = 9

    # the n x n array
    x = [[0]*n]*n

    # the input number converted as a string
    aux = "900000001051200030000980000680740000730000908010058670008100000002007090190004060"

    k = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            x[i][j] = aux[k]
            k = k + 1
```

then for printing the matrix x you do:

```
import numpy as np

# print the modified array x
print(np.matrix(x))
```

which gives the output:

```
[['9' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '1']
 ['0' '5' '1' '2' '0' '0' '0' '3' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '9' '8' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['6' '8' '0' '7' '4' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['7' '3' '0' '0' '0' '0' '9' '0' '8']
 ['0' '1' '0' '0' '5' '8' '6' '7' '0']
 ['0' '0' '8' '1' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '2' '0' '0' '7' '0' '9' '0']
 ['1' '9' '0' '0' '0' '4' '0' '6' '0']]
```

Comment: You can replace your array with ```import numpy as np``` 
```x = np.zeroes((9,9))``` so you don't need to hand type the lists. :P

Comment: @Enthus3d Then getting error. No module name numpy found.

Comment: @Poojan install numpy using ‘’’pip install numpy’’’, you’re missing that module.

Comment: @Enthus3d But i am not allowed to install 3rd party modules.

Comment: you need numpy array for printing the 2d matrix x. if you dont need to print it then remove the numpy package and remove the last printing command. it works perfect